# How do I know which gem requires a dependency to another one which can't be installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, bundle

I'm upgrading a Ruby on Rails software on Linux CentOS 6, and when running

```
bundle install
```

it stops on:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, the dependencies in the gemfiles I know of do NOT require nokogiri 1.8.0, they check for my installed version of Ruby, and only require 1.6.8 if I don't have Ruby 2.1.

I have tried

```
gem dependency nokogiri --reverse-dependencies
```

but as version 1.8.0 is not installed, it is not listed in reverse dependencies.

So where could I get the info on which gem or gemfile is actually trying to force me to use nokogiri 1.8.0?

[edit: I have replaced the output of bundle install of my old version with the new version, 1.15.2, as it now gives different information]
The output of bundle install --verbose:

```
Fetching rdoc 5.1.0
Installing rdoc 5.1.0
Using redcarpet 3.3.4
0:  redcarpet (3.3.4) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/redcarpet-3.3.4.gemspec
Using redis 3.3.3
0:  redis (3.3.3) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/redis-3.3.3.gemspec
Using request_store 1.0.5
0:  request_store (1.0.5) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/request_store-1.0.5.gemspec
Using tilt 2.0.7
0:  tilt (2.0.7) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/tilt-2.0.7.gemspec
Using rmagick 2.16.0
0:  rmagick (2.16.0) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rmagick-2.16.0.gemspec
Using ruby-ole 1.2.12.1
0:  ruby-ole (1.2.12.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/ruby-ole-1.2.12.1.gemspec
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
0:  rubyzip (1.2.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rubyzip-1.2.1.gemspec
Using simplecov-html 0.9.0
0:  simplecov-html (0.9.0) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/simplecov-html-0.9.0.gemspec
Using tiny_tds 0.6.2
0:  tiny_tds (0.6.2) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/tiny_tds-0.6.2.gemspec
Using vcard 0.2.15
0:  vcard (0.2.15) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/vcard-0.2.15.gemspec
Using yard 0.9.9
0:  yard (0.9.9) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/yard-0.9.9.gemspec
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
0:  tzinfo (1.2.3) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/tzinfo-1.2.3.gemspec
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.0
Installing nokogiri 1.8.0 with native extensions
Using rack-test 0.6.3
0:  rack-test (0.6.3) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rack-test-0.6.3.gemspec
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
0:  rack-protection (1.5.3) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rack-protection-1.5.3.gemspec
Using vegas 0.1.11
0:  vegas (0.1.11) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/vegas-0.1.11.gemspec
Using mime-types 3.1
0:  mime-types (3.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/mime-types-3.1.gemspec
Using addressable 2.5.1
0:  addressable (2.5.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/addressable-2.5.1.gemspec
Using childprocess 0.7.1
0:  childprocess (0.7.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/childprocess-0.7.1.gemspec
Using sprockets 3.7.1
0:  sprockets (3.7.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/sprockets-3.7.1.gemspec
Using redmine_crm 0.0.31
0:  redmine_crm (0.0.31) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/redmine_crm-0.0.31.gemspec
Using mocha 1.2.1
0:  mocha (1.2.1) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/mocha-1.2.1.gemspec
Using rack-openid 1.4.2
0:  rack-openid (1.4.2) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rack-openid-1.4.2.gemspec
Using rbpdf 1.19.2
0:  rbpdf (1.19.2) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/specifications/rbpdf-1.19.2.gemspec
Gem::InstallError: rdoc requires RubyGems version >= 2.2. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:541:in `ensure_required_rubygems_version_met'
```

Comment: could you run `bundle install --verbose` and post the output? also, could you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I had tried with --verbose, but couldn't find any useful info in it:

Comment: I added the --verbose results in the original post.
Regarding the main gemfile, it is the one of redmine 3.4.2:
https://bitbucket.org/redmine/redmine/src/59f64ccf3604022d4400b5884acea86b9fc5b4fa/Gemfile?at=3.4-stable&fileviewer=file-view-default
but I ran bundle install with the code of redmine 3.4.1 this morning, and did not get any error, so I am puzzled with what happened (not many changes between 3.4.1 and 3.4.2, and none looks to involve gems related to nokogiri).

Comment: When I run `bundle install` I get output like this: `Fetching rake 12.0.0, 
Installing rake 12.0.0, 
Fetching i18n 0.7.0, 
Installing i18n 0.7.0, 
` even if the bundle hits an error. Did you not get any output about which gems were being installed?

Comment: A few `gems` that are rails dependencies (including `rails-dom-testing`)  rely on `nokogiri`. See rails [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile.lock)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running an old version of bundler (1.9.1) which may not have proper support for ruby versioning. Try running `gem update bundler` and running `bundle install` with the new version.

Comment: Indeed, after updating the bundler, I have different information. It now tells me that it's rdoc 5.1 that it can't install...

Comment: I don't understand...
I've run bundle install again (without the --verbose), and it worked.
I ran it again with --verbose, and no issue anymore. Problem solved, but I don't really understand why.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the issue was coming from using an old version of the bundler (1.9.1).

Upgrading it to the latest version with `gem update bundler` moved me to version 1.15.2, and then, bundle install worked (at the second execution, but it did succeed in the end).